# Getting the contents of a ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms `ListView` set up like this

```
public class AddressView : ContentPage
{
    public AddressView()
    {
        this.Title = "Native address book";
        CreateView();
    }

    async void CreateView()
    {
        IAddress addresses = DependencyService.Get<IAddress>();
        var addressList = addresses.ContactDetails();
        if (addressList.Count == 0)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No contacts", "Your phone has no contacts stored on it", "OK");
            return;
        }

        if (Device.OS != TargetPlatform.iOS)
            BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        else
            Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);

        var myList = new ListView()
        {
            ItemsSource = addressList,
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(MyLayout))
        };
        myList.ItemSelected += MyList_ItemSelected;

        Content = myList;
    }

    void MyList_ItemSelected (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as ViewCell;
    }
}

public class MyLayout : ViewCell
{
    public MyLayout()
    {
        var label = new Label()
        {
            Text = "name",
            Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Default),
            TextColor = Color.Blue
        };

        var numberLabel = new Label()
        {
            Text = "number",
            Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Small),
            TextColor = Color.Black
        };

        this.BindingContextChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            var item = (KeyValuePair<string,string>)BindingContext;
            label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Key"));
            numberLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Value"));
        };

        View = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            Padding = new Thickness(12, 8),
            Children = { label, numberLabel }
        };
    }
}
```

This grabs the address book from the native platform (and works fine). What I'm trying to do is read the two Text properties from the labels within the ViewCell in the DataTemplate.

Is there a way to iterate through the children within the ViewCell to find the values of the labels within the cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the problem is in the MyList_ItemSelected event handler because you're being passed the binding context for the cell (in this case, e.SelectedItem is the KeyValuePair from the Dictionary), rather than the cell itself?

I can't see a way to get a reference to the Cell directly inside the event handler.

However, by changing the value of your Dictionary to be a class rather than a simple string, you can add a WeakReference to the Cell:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Text {get;set;}
    public WeakReference<MyLayout> Layout { get;set;}

    public Address (string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}

public interface IAddress
{
    Dictionary<string,Address> ContactDetails ();
}

public MyLayout()
{
    // ... Removed for brevity

    this.BindingContextChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        var item = (KeyValuePair<string,Address>)BindingContext;
        label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Key"));
        numberLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Value.Text"));
        item.Value.Layout = new WeakReference<MyLayout>(this);
    };

    // ... Removed for brevity
}
```

So, now the value in the event handler will have a reference to the ViewCell. Note that I used a WeakReference to avoid a strong reference cycle.

```
void MyList_ItemSelected (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var kvp = (KeyValuePair<string,Address>)e.SelectedItem;
    var item = kvp.Value;
    MyLayout cell;
    item.Layout.TryGetTarget (out cell);

    // Now that you have a reference to the ViewCell, you can access the 
    // View properties.
}
```